# slideable menu cycle with next and previous buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I'm trying to make a "cycling menu" or selector.

I've made a jsfiddle that looks like [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/4zHDt/7/)

I've tried this:

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
      $('#routesheader').animate({
          left: '200px';
      });
      $('#routesheader').toggle();
});
$("#next").click(function(){
      $('#routesheader').animate({
          left: '-200px';
      });
      $('#routesheader').toggle();
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I want the list to move to the left and right based on what button is pressed and thus, revealing the next/previous choise

If possible id like to do it without plugins (such as JQuery Cycle)

Comment: you using animate incorrectly... something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/4zHDt/9/ ? obviously there is more to be done to accomplish what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the semicolon in the animate brackets. That's incorrect syntax. The correct syntax is like so:

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
    $('#routesheader').animate({left:'200px'},500);
    $('#routesheader').toggle();
});
$("#next").click(function(){
    $('#routesheader').animate({left:'-200px'},500);
    $('#routesheader').toggle();
});
```

If you need more than one property to animate, divide like so:

```
$("#prev").click(function(){
    $('#routesheader').animate({
        left:'200px',
        attr:'value',
        attr:'value'
    },500);
```

You have to use commas, but don't use a comma on the last property. Javascript is very sensitive to proper syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still cant get it to work.
This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/litari/4zHDt/7/ I've also tried your seccond solution. Do you mind providing a working JSfiddle for me?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4zHDt/12/ This should at least get you heading in the right direction.